# In Django which version is now stable in 2019?

Tags: python, django

I was using django 1.1 and python2.7 in my project.

Now I will setup a new Django project from scratch. So i want to know if the above configuration is correct for my new project or I should use python3  and latest django version. If so then which Django,Python version will be good for new project? And I should get good support from django community.

Thanks

Comment: See https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ for the latest stable version. Python 2.x is not supported anymore.

Comment: I would say using Python 2.7 is very discouraged for most kind of new projects.

Comment: Use Django 2.x with Python 3.6+

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently, the last stable version of Django is 2.1.7. This version works with Python 3.7. You'll find a lot of support for this version of Django... there are a lot of develops about this version, such as Django Rest Framework, JWT, among others.

I suggest you for a project from scratch, work with Django 2.1.7 and Python 3.7, probably, you'll get quickly your goals. If you need to update your knowledge, you can do a course on a web platform as Udemy.

Soon Django 2.2 will be released... but I suppose we have to wait some days to get all benefits of this new release.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. It will be so much useful for me.